# Combine two functions with conditional (if) switch in Gekko

Tags: python, conditional-statements, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I have two thermodynamic relationships for low (300-1000K) and high (1000-3000K) temperatures. If I want to use both of these in Gekko, how can I combine them into a single correlation that I can use in an optimization problem?

Here is a section of Python code that calculates either the low or high temperature relationship from 300K to 3000K.

[image: Heat capacity for Methane]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(300.0,3000.0,50)

a_lo = np.array([ 5.15,-1.37E-02,4.92E-05,-4.85E-08,1.67E-11])
a_hi = np.array([7.49E-02,1.34E-02,-5.73E-06,1.22E-09,-1.02E-13])
i_lo = np.where(np.logical_and(T>=300.0, T<1000.0))
i_hi = np.where(np.logical_and(T>=1000.0, T<=3000.0))
cp = np.zeros(50)
Rg = 8.314 # J/mol-K
cp[i_lo] = a_lo[0] + a_lo[1]*T[i_lo] + a_lo[2]*T[i_lo]**2.0 + \
             a_lo[3]*T[i_lo]**3.0 + a_lo[4]*T[i_lo]**4.0
cp[i_hi] = a_hi[0] + a_hi[1]*T[i_hi] + a_hi[2]*T[i_hi]**2.0 + \
             a_hi[3]*T[i_hi]**3.0 + a_hi[4]*T[i_hi]**4.0
cp *= Rg

plt.plot(T,cp,'k-',lw=5)
plt.plot(T[i_lo],cp[i_lo],'.',color='orange')
plt.plot(T[i_hi],cp[i_hi],'.',color='red')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)'); plt.grid()
plt.ylabel(r'$CH_4$ Heat Capacity $\left(\frac{J}{mol-K}\right)$')
plt.show()
```

I tried using a conditional (if) statement in building my model but it only uses the correlation that is selected from the initialized values. If temperature `T` is a variable in my model, I want it to switch to one or the other based on the temperature variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to use a conditional function in your optimization or simulation problem. The first approach not exact but may be a suitable approximation by using a cubic spline that creates an interpolation between sampled points (see **approach #1**). The second approach is exact but requires either an Mathematical Program with Complementarity Constraints (MPCC) with `if2()` or an Integer Switch variable with `if3()` (see **approach #2**). These two approaches are discussed in the Design Optimization Course page on [Logical Conditions in Optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# CH4 Heat capacity parameters (LO: 300-1000K, HI: 1000K-3000K)
a_lo = np.array([ 5.15,-1.37E-02,4.92E-05,-4.85E-08,1.67E-11])
a_hi = np.array([7.49E-02,1.34E-02,-5.73E-06,1.22E-09,-1.02E-13])
Rg = 8.314 # J/mol-K
m  = GEKKO()

# Approach #1: Cubic Spline
def cp1(T):
    if T>=300 and T<=1000:
        a = a_lo
    elif T>1000 and T<=3000:
        a = a_hi
    else:
        raise Exception('Temperature ' + str(T) + ' out of range')
    cp = (a[0]+a[1]*T+a[2]*T**2.0+a[3]*T**3.0+a[4]*T**4.0)*Rg
    return cp
# Calculate cp at 50 pts
T = np.linspace(300.0,3000.0,50)
cp = [cp1(Ti) for Ti in T]
x1 = m.Var(lb=300,ub=3000); y1 = m.Var()
m.cspline(x1,y1,T,cp)

# Approach #2: Gekko conditional statements
def cp2(a,T):
    return (a[0]+a[1]*T+a[2]*T**2.0+a[3]*T**3.0+a[4]*T**4.0)*Rg
x2  = m.Var(lb=300,ub=3000)
y2a = m.Intermediate(cp2(a_lo,x2)); 
y2b = m.Intermediate(cp2(a_hi,x2)); 
y2  = m.if3(x2-1000,y2a,y2b)

m.Equation(y1==80)
m.Equation(y2==80)

m.solve()

print('Find Temperature where cp=80 J/mol-K')
print(x1.value[0],x2.value[0])
```